# Conversion de hora de tipo string a datetime en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo esta duad. Tengo un combobox, que tiene horarios a modo de lista, que tengo que utilizar para turnos. La fecha la saco de un datetimpicker. La hora la tengo en string así: 10:00 o 14:45.

**¿Cómo puedo hacer para juntar la fecha del datetimepicker y luego el horario seleccionado del combobox convertirlo a DateTime y unirla a la fecha?**

He leído toda la documentación con respecto a esto en microsoft, pero no me da una solución. Convierte todo junto, o solo la fecha. Traté de tomar la hora por un lado, los minutos por otro, y sumárselos a la fecha, pero no me sale.

**¿Hay algúna forma específica para hacer esto?**

Comment: ¿Qué has probado hasta ahora? Enseña algo de tu código para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías intentar concatenar los `strings` y usar el método `DateTime.TryParse`, revisa siguiente ejemplo que te anexo.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        String fechaString;     
        fechaString = "2020-10-27";
        Console.WriteLine(fechaString);     
        string horaString = "10:20";
        Console.WriteLine(horaString);
        
        string fechaYHora = fechaString + " " + horaString;
        Console.WriteLine(fechaYHora);
        
        DateTime result;
        DateTime.TryParse(fechaYHora,out result);
        
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToShortDateString() + " " + result.ToShortTimeString());
                
    }
}
```

También puedes extraer cada parte de la fecha y de la hora y después crear una variable de tipo `DateTime`:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string fechaString = "2020-10-27";
        string horaString = "14:20";
        
        //Extraer año del fechaString
        string syear = fechaString.Substring(0,4);  
        //Extraer mes del fechaString   
        string smonth = fechaString.Substring(5,2);
        //Extraer dia del fechaString   
        string sday = fechaString.Substring(8,2);
        //Estraer horas
        string shora = horaString.Substring(0,2);
        //Estraer minutos
        string sminuto = horaString.Substring(3,2);
        

        Console.WriteLine("años: " + syear);        
        Console.WriteLine("mes: " + smonth);
        Console.WriteLine("dia: " + sday);
        Console.WriteLine("hora: " + shora);
        Console.WriteLine("minuto: " + sminuto);
        
        //Convertir a int
        int year,month,day, hora, minuto;
        int.TryParse(syear, out year);
        int.TryParse(smonth, out month);
        int.TryParse(sday, out day);
        int.TryParse(shora, out hora);
        int.TryParse(sminuto, out minuto);

        
        DateTime fechaConHora = new DateTime(year, month, day, hora, minuto, 0);
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(fechaConHora.ToShortDateString() + " " + fechaConHora.ToShortTimeString());
                
    }
}
```

Comment: Sos una genia, gracias! Ahora entendí qué es lo que no me estaba saliendo del código que yo escribía.

Comment: Genial, un placer ayudarte. :)